# Is there a cleanup tool that will clean a php file with html inside...

Tags: php, html

I've been checking all over and the choice everyone raves about don't work and I got a lot of code to tidy up. My code is mixed with php echo's some functions, and a lot of html. I have an includes for 99% of my php, am frustrated searching...

Lint and Tidy don't work for me... Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/** by selecting **html/php** in the option menu, and then select more advanced option to clean it.

Comment: That was perfect, thank you... I'll pay it forward at lunch by giving a homeless person some money and tell them it's from Vixed...